# Combined Pie Chart and Bar Plot - Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to get a very similiar output compared to the example explained and shown here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/bar_of_pie.html?highlight=bar%20pie

So far so good. I even managed to get a second barplot but obviously the commands for formatting this second plot are ignored. The code shown below gives the following ouput:

[image: Python Output]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
import numpy as np
import math


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)


#pie chart
labels = ['Completed', 'Not completed']
ratios = [27.09, 72.91]
startangle = -45
explode = [0.1, 0]  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')
ax1.pie(ratios, autopct='%1.1f%%', explode=explode, labels=labels, startangle=startangle)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.


#bar chart #1
xpos = 0
bottom = 0
ratio_boys = [45.0, 55.0]
width = 0.1
colors = ['red', 'grey']

for j in range(len(ratio_boys)):
    height = ratio_boys[j]
    ax2.bar(xpos, height, width, bottom=bottom, color=colors[j])
    ypos = bottom + ax2.patches[j].get_height()/2
    bottom += height
    ax2.text(xpos,ypos, "%1.1f%%" %
        (ax2.patches[j].get_height()), ha='center')    

plt.title('Boys')
ax2.axis('off')
plt.xlim(-2.5*width, 2.5*width)


#bar chart #2
xpos = 0
bottom = 0
ratio_girls = [8.6, 91.4]
width = 0.1
colors = ['red', 'grey']

for j in range(len(ratio_girls)):
    height = ratio_girls[j]
    ax3.bar(xpos, height, width, bottom=bottom, color=colors[j])
    ypos = bottom + ax3.patches[j].get_height()/2
    bottom += height
    ax3.text(xpos,ypos, "%1.1f%%" %
        (ax3.patches[j].get_height()), ha='center')    

plt.title('Girls', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax3.axis('off')
plt.xlim(-2.5*width, 2.5*width)
```

The desired output should look slightly different. Like this:

[image: Desired Output]

What do I have to change? And what does this (-0.25, 0.25) at the upper left border mean? Where does this come from?

Comment: You should use `axs.set_title('boys')` instead of `plt.title()`, Have a look at the [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Comment: `(-0.25, 0.25)` is the output of the last command, when you use matplotlib (or Python code in general) in an interactive environment (e.g. Jupyter). You can suppress it adding a semicolon (`;`) which introduces a dummy empty command.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. The title thing is now working perfectly fine. Also the (-0.25, 0.25) disappeared now.

But how to manage making the 'Boys' Barplot as slim as the 'Girls' Barplot?

Comment: You'd use [`gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) with `width_ratios`. As in `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(...), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [6, 1, 1]})`

Comment: I finally managed it. Thank you very much.